# cakephp foreach error

Tags: cakephp, view

when trying to run this code cake is throwing an error with our foreach loop in the view, i will include the model, controller and view. The end goal of this code is to print out the users own invoices and not every invoice in the database.

model

```
<?php
    class Invoice extends AppModel{ 
    var $name='invoice'; 
    public $useTable = 'invoices';
    public $primaryKey = 'id';}
```

controller with relevant functions

```
<?php

class InvoicesController extends AppController{

    public function index(){
            $this->set('title_for_layout', 'indexPage');
        }


public function payinvoice($id = null){
        $this->set('title_for_layout', 'Pay Invoice');
        $this->set('stylesheet_used', 'homestyle');
        $this->set('image_used', 'eBOXLogoHome.jpg');   
        $this->layout='home_layout';


        $this->set('invoice', $this->Invoice->read(null, $id));
} 

 public function viewinvoice(){
        $this->set('title_for_layout', 'View invoice');
        $this->set('stylesheet_used', 'homestyle');
        $this->set('image_used', 'eBOXLogoHome.jpg');   
}
```

view file

```
<table width="100%" border="1">

            <table width="100%" border="1">
                <tr>
                    <th>Biller</th>
                    <th>Subject</th>
                    <th>Date</th>
                    <th>Action</th>
                </tr>
            <?php foreach($invoice as $invoice): ?>
            <tr><td align='center'>
<?php echo $this->Html->link($invoice['Invoice']['biller'], 
array('action' => 'viewinvoice', $invoice['Invoice']['id'])); ;?> </td>
<td align='center'><?php echo $invoice['Invoice']['subject']; ?></td>
<td align='center'><?php echo $invoice['Invoice']['datecreated']; ?></td>
<td align='center'><a href="viewinvoice"><button>View Invoice</button></a><a href="disputeinvoice"><button>Dispute Invoice</button></a></td>
</tr><?php endforeach; ?>

            </table>
```

Comment: have you tried like... using different variable name for the `as` in the `foreach`?

Comment: it throws a comment saying unexpected T_String for the foreach line

Comment: `foreach($invoice as $invoice):`??? XD Come on! you know what's the problem with that =P

Comment: you can always `debug($this->viewVars);` to see what data is being set and in what format.

Comment: Editing a post bumps it in the activity list as if it were a freshly posted question, so feel free to give editing a go. Or just post a new question with new code, if it's too different from this.

Answer (score 2):

Couple of points:

```
foreach($invoice as $invoice):
```

should be:

```
foreach($invoices as $invoice):
```

As mentioned by a few other people.

But the fundamental problem is that the data structure you are reading into $invoice is one record, not an array of multiple records.

You can do away with the foreach all together:

Answer (score 1):

I spotted a couple of issues with your code, you should clear these up and try again (I don't think the error is on the foreach line like you say it is)

```
class Invoice extends AppModel{ 
    var $name='invoice'; 
    public $useTable = 'invoices';
    public $primaryKey = 'id';
}
```

All the properties you are defining here are the defaults, so there's no need to define them, the only one you might need is `var $name` if you're using PHP 4, otherwise your model could just be:

```
class Invoice extends AppModel{ }
```

Next, try not to name your foreach iterator variable the same as the array you are iterating over, *this could possibly be the cause your problem*. Personally I tend to call the array `$items` and then each element inside it `$item`.

```
<?php foreach($invoices as $invoice): ?>
```

That way you're not accidentally going to overwrite something in the original array...